# Using "have" or "had" for an ongoing relationship

Tags: tense

What would be the proper grammar for this sentence when using *have* and *had*? Which is correct (it's about relationship that is still existing for 28 years until now):

> - It's the best relationship I ever **have**.
> - It's the best relationship I ever **had**.

Comment: The use of *ever* implies "in my past life before now", so only *had* really sounds correct.

Answer (score 1):

I believe your answer is a mix of both. It shows it's your favourite and on-going:

> "It's the best relationship I have ever had"

Comment: Simple past *had* isn't necessarily incorrect, however. *The best relationship I had as a teenager is the same one I have had through all the years since.*

Comment: @choster - True. Also true: Using _have_ is incorrect unless we restructure the sentence (such as, "It's the best relationship I will ever have").